# offline installation of cygwin is impossible

Tags: installation, cygwin, offline

I need to install cygwin on some machine not connected to internet so I did everything I found over the internet on the subject.

But despite I "download without installing" ALL packages from a normal machine (I got almost 20G) despite I transfert that to the non connected machines when trying to "Install from local directory" install it is just telling: "nothing to install/update" I tried any options and still the same.

Does that really works recently? I asked recently because any articles I found on subject are years ago...

Jérôme

Comment: have you selected any package and the proper cache ?

Comment: there si nothing listed and I tried all options

Comment: ask support on the cygwin mailing list